# FontAwesome CDN not loading

Tags: html, css, font-face, font-awesome

http://themes.grozav.com/smartistic/

Can someone help me with this? It's displaying a square on the menu bar.

Comment: Please see this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your style.css There is a line:

```
* {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
}
```

This line overrides the font awesome font. If you disable this line the camera icon works. You might want to set the font-family to the body of the page instead of every object by using the asterisk.

As Rocket Hazmat pointed out, you could also remove the !important from your css. In this way it doesn't overrule the font awesome font definition.

Comment: Or just remove the `!important`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I completely forgot about that. Really appreciate it!